# Spring Batch to generate steps dynamically corresponding to job though the program

Tags: oracle11g, spring-batch

As I have the requirement of creating multiple steps for a single job based upon some conditions parameters through standalone java program can anyone able to share the code snippet program corresponding for that.
Thanks for the response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Spring Batch jobs be configured at run time with dynamic steps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236525/can-spring-batch-jobs-be-configured-at-run-time-with-dynamic-steps)

Answer (score 0):

Create a whole job with all steps you may need.
Add some [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) in job's flow to skip/repeat step.
This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Do you have any sample example luc if you plz provide code snippet so that I can check it suits to me with my requirement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374899/how-to-skip-batch-step-when-condition-is-false or https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#programmaticFlowDecisions

Comment: Thanks for the Reply I have verified the above link but it doesn,t suit my requirement let me explain in you in detail.

Comment: <job id="job1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"  restartable="true">
 
      <!--- Gerneration of the below steps should be happened dynamically based upon the input value like list of
            Steps value -->
  <step id="step1" >
       <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="stepReader"
                             processor="stepProcessor" writer="stepWriter"
                commit-interval="1000" retry-limit="3" >  
                  </chunk>         
              </tasklet>   
  </step>
</job>

This should be programatically generated not any harcoded in the xml.